# php mailer sending the mail in pieces

Tags: php, email

sending mail using php mailer but the mail receiving in 3 parts as i am asking 3 things name email and query.and i am receiving these all 3 information in 3 different time with in the mail and also even after getting the write email format getting the error message that invalid format. please check and try solve it.
so can you help me getting know, where i am mistaken? please solve.

```
<?php

$name = $email = $query = "";
$name_err = $email_err = $query_err = "";

if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty ( $_POST ["name"] )) {
        $name_err = 'Please Enter Your Name';
    } else {
        $name = sendmail ( $_POST ["name"] );
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ["email"] )) {
        $email_err = 'Please Enter Your Email Id';
    } else {
        $email = sendmail ( $_POST ["email"] );

        if (!filter_var ( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {
            $email_err = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ["query"] )) {
        $query_err = 'Please type your query';
    } else {
        $query = sendmail ( $_POST ["query"] );
    }
}

function validate_email($data) {
    $data = trim ( $data );
    $data = stripslashes ( $data );
    $data = htmlspecialchars ( $data );

    return $data;
    $message = $data;
}


function sendmail($message) {

    //require_once ("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    //require_once ("PHPMailer/class.smtp.php");

    require_once ("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

    $subject = "Visitor Query";
    $from = "007shiva007@gmail.com"; // example a@b.com
    $password = 'password';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $body = $message;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // sets SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->Username = $from; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $password; // SMTP password

    $mail->AddAddress ( "partyushgoyal@gmail.com" );

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->From = $from;
    $mail->ContentType = "text/html";

    $result = $mail->Send();

}
?>
```

Comment: If that's your real password remove it immediately.

Comment: I would go ahead and change your password Pratyush Goyal..  I saw it, so it's safe to say that I'm not the only one...

Comment: i'ts not the real password

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. First prepare your message and if everything is filled (no errors are there), send e-mail.

```
$message = '';
$error = array();

if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty ( $_POST ["name"] )) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Name';
    } else {
        $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<br>';
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ["email"] )) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Email Id';
    } else {
        if (!filter_var ( $_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {
            $error[] = "Invalid email format";
        } else {
            $message .= 'e-mail: ' .$_POST["email"] . '<br>';
        }
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ["query"] )) {
        $error[] = 'Please type your query';
    } else {
        $message .= 'message: ' . $_POST["query"];
    }
}

if (count($error == 0)) {
    // SEND MAIL
} else {
    // show error messages
}
```

Comment: not getting the email id entered in the form, from this code

Comment: You had mistake in your code too, it couldn't work correctly. I've updated my answer, 13th line: `if (!filter_var ( $_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {`. Than I put there into `$message` labels and `<br>` to format your message if you didn't do it yet :-)

Comment: hiii, can you help me about i am receiving the email values in one line, 
how to get each value in different line

Comment: @PratyushGoyal: yesterday I updated my code, added there `<br>`s to break lines. In `$message` you can use HTML, inline styles, etc. Everything what you need.

Comment: hey .. there ? code is working fine on localhost, but its not working online :(